# Cant run jest puppeteer automation on docker image

Tags: docker, jestjs, dockerfile, puppeteer

I have jest automation with puppeteer that needs to run as a docker container. but after the build when I try to run it. I get this error `Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/setup.js, reason: Failed to launch the browser process! /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-884014/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I'm quit new for the docker stuff not sure what I'm doing wrong here

jest.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles:['dotenv/config'],
  preset: "jest-puppeteer",
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
}
```

jest-puppeteer.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  launch: {
    headless: true, //Specify whether to launch UI
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized', '--disable-gpu', 
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
          '--no-sandbox'],
  },
  testEnvironmentOptions: { resources: 'usable' },
};
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD npm run test
```

I installed chrome separately into docker and tried to run it but that didn't work.

Comment: How did you suppose to run the chrome in UI mode in a docker container?

Comment: that is not what causing this problem. I tried with headless too

Answer (score 0):

I use this docker image and it fixed the issue

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/alekzonder/puppeteer/
```